# Encoding problem in Google AppEngine when BlobstoreUploadHandler

Tags: python, google-app-engine, unicode

I am seeing weird characters in the datastore when reading them in BlobstoreUploadHandler. The problem is only on Google servers, everything works great on the development server.

This usually works:

```
item = models.Item()
item.description = self.request.get("description")
item.put()
```

However, if this is within a BlobstoreUploadHandler, the description text is all messed up. The corrupted characters or on the form '=XX', where X is a hex. Line breaks are also corrupted.

Explanation on how it is best to deal with unicode in user submitted content would be appreciated.

Update:
It is a [known bug](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2749). I still don't have a workaround yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known bug, check [**Blobstore handler breaking data encoding**](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2749) issue.
Performing a POST to a Blobstore handler, test fields are getting converted to **MIME quoted printable** format.

I think you could workaround this using [quopri](http://docs.python.org/library/quopri.html) Python standard module.

Comment: using the input from that issue (żarówka), I get 'xbxhcsOzd2th'. I can't find a decode method that can get back the input.

Comment: This seems to work for me: quopri.decodestring(foo).decode('iso8859-1')

Comment: It does seem to work but I am not confident that I will always get a ISO8859-1 MIME quoted printable format. This is also just partly resolved because this breaks on the development server (no ISO8859-1 there)